# How to set Bootstrap margin for element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

So I'm using only Bootstrap classes to style my HTML and I have a  tag that is almost touching the element above it. I want some space between them so I am attempting to use Bootstrap's Spacing utility class.

What I have is:

```
<h3 class="text-center m-t-2">Widely Known For</h3>
```

I'm under the impression that the class "m-t-2" (margin-top-2rem) should provide me with the space I'm looking for, but it's not making a difference.

Am I supposed to assign the class and *then* use it as a selector to edit with custom CSS?

As I am strictly using only Bootstrap classes, if that is the case, then I won't be wanting to use it for this particular project I'm working on.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I recommend you show a simple example of your problem. Fork this: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

Comment: is m-t-2 is a bootstrap 4 class which is not fully released yet so avoid using bootstrap 4 classes till is finally out.

Comment: Bootstrap is a starting point, not an out-of-the-box solution. You should always be prepared to use the included classes as a starting point and modify certain elements to suit your needs. Needless to say, @DhavalChheda is also correct, you should be using the BS3 release instead of the BS4 prerelease unless you're confident with working through any bugs.

Comment: @DhavalChheda Oh Kay.